# How to export data from a Lotus private view into excel file?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript

I'm experimenting with Lotus private views for the first time and I finally made a private view.

Now i need to export this view to excel file... it is possible run one lotusscript to do this?

i´m not admin so i haven´t privileges for run an agent.

how?

tks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be possible to write a LotusScript Agent to export. But if the view contains all the data you need and there are not too much documents, then simply right- click on one document after selecting all of them with Ctrl + A and click "Copy as Table"
Then paste the result in Excel...

To write a lotusScript- Agent to export the data, you need the rights to do so, and usually admins don't give the rights to "normal" users...

If you have the right and the knowledge to do something like this, then it would look like this in an agent that exports the complete content of the view (not tested):

```
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim viw as NotesView
Dim viwNav as NotesViewNavigator
Dim ve as NotesViewEntry
Set viw = ws.CurrentView.View
Set viwNav = viw.CreateViewNavigator

Dim xlApp As Variant
Dim xlsheet As Variant

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlsheet = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1)
Set ve=viwNav.GetFirstEntry()
Col = 1
Row = 1
While not ve is Nothing
  Forall colval in ve.ColumnValues
    xlsheet.Cells(row,col).Value = colval
    Col = col + 1
  End Forall
  Set ve = viwNav.GetNextEntry(ve)
  Row = Row + 1
Wend
```

This does not take into account, that ColumnValues can be arrays (depending on the view settings), has no error handling and does not check any validity...
But it can serve as a base to begin with...

Comment: i put this code on viewer design » QueryOpen but the code have errors... :/

Comment: Yes, that was, what I said: It is untested and may contain errors. And you did not tell, that you want to do this automatically... This Code MIGHT work in QueryOpen, but as written: It is just a base to begin...

Comment: This question has been bumped to the StackOverflow homepage for review, which brought it back to my attention. For automation, I have a feeling that QueryOpen is not the right place because a QueryOpen script runs before the view is opened. I have a feeling you can't create a ViewNavigator before the view is opened. I would put this into an Action button within the private view instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can export to a CSV file, which Excel can read, and you don't need to do any programming.  Just open your view, pull down the File menu and select Export.  Type a filename into the Export dialog and select "Comma Separated Value" in the "Save as type" dropdown.  A small CSV Export dialog should appear and you will be able to select a few options, which are pretty straightforward.

Comment: Tks but... how can i do this auto? something like on "queryopen" run export code to excel...

Comment: You can automate it in formula language, with @Command( [FileExport] ; fileType ; fileName ).  However, I believe that the final options dialog will appear and you will have to click "OK" in order to complete the export, so it will only be partially automated.

Comment: BTW: I think that QueryOpen is probably not the right place to try to automate an export, as QueryOpen actually occurs just before the view is opened -- therefore the view is not yet loaded, so I doubt you can export it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it in UI is to select all documents (CTRL+A), and from Edit menu use Copy As/Table. Then paste into Excel.

You can delete first column (doclinks).

This approach is not reproducible with @Formula or Lotusscript.